# How to fix thymeleaf syntax error in html?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

When I use thymeleaf to write a HTML page, I got a syntax error in IntelliJ IDEA.But I was able to run the program normally.

screenshot:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo0oo2015/TuChuang/master/Snipaste_2019-05-09_21-30-48.png

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-cmn-Hans" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p th:text="${name}">name</p>
  <p th:text="'Hello! ' + ${name} + '!'">hello world</p>
  <p th:text="|Hello! ${name}!|">hello world</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: Why IDEA shows this error and how to make it not show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211477). Please follow YouTrack ticket for updates.

UPDATE: the issue was fixed and the fix should be available in the next IntelliJ IDEA release (2019.2).